# How to sum of all Map values except one Key's value

Tags: flutter, dart

For a learning I have created a list of Map ..I want to sum all of the key's value except month number like...in short I want to make loop for key's value

for seeing output.i have taken list tile where title should show some of expenses and leading shows month number

```
{
 'Month':1,
'Lightbill':305,
'Provisional':503,
}
```

Now I want like this

```
1 808
```

here is my basic code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  List<Map<String,int>> mylist=[
    {
      'Month':1,
      'Provisional': 4500,
      'Teaexp': 980,
      'Lightbill': 1240,
      'Assets': 399,
    },

    { 'Month':2,
      'Provisional': 0250,
      'Teaexp': 150,
      'Lightbill': 240,
      'Assets': 30,
    }
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: List.generate(mylist.length, (index) {
              int sum=0;
              sum=sum+int.parse(mylist[index]['Provisional'].toString());
              
              return Container(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading:CircleAvatar(child:
                    Text(mylist[index]['Month'].toString()),),

                  title: Text(sum.toString()),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all values like `myMap.values` and to skip 1st I am using `.skip()` and then to sum up using `reduce`.

```dart
final sum = mylist[index]
    .values
    .skip(1)
    .reduce((value, element) => value + element);
```

More about [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/Map-class.html) and [`List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/List-class.html)

Comment: Note, this works on while map 1st item is month as you’ve attached on question, For more dynamic approach you can test Ivo Beckers or Maurits van Beusekom's answers

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming all the map value are non null and has type int.
you can achieve like it -

```
Text(
"${(mylist[index]["Lightbill"] as int)  + (mylist[index]["Provisional"] as int)+ (mylist[index]["Teaexp"] as int)}"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
Text((mylist[index].values.sum - mylist[index]['Month']!).toString())
```

This needs

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

to use sum

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it would be to use the `keys` property to retrieve a list of all keys and filter it:

```dart
int sum(Map<String, int> input) {
  int sum = 0;
  input
    .keys
    .where((String key) => key != 'Month')
    .forEach((String key) => sum += input[key]);
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: `final sum = map.entries.whereNot((e) => e.key == 'Month').map((e) => e.value).sum;`